# Switch causes a method to become non static? So do if statements?

Tags: java

What causes a method to become "Non-Static"?

I've been trying to get this coin toss to work. Sadly a few decades (at least it feels like it) passed  and all I figured out is that if (feel free to correct me) a if statement/switch is inside a method, it makes the method non-static. So how does one get around this error. Important stuff to know: `p1Choose` starts out true. I want this method to return true if the person won the coin toss (if `p1Choose` is true then its player 1 and if it is false then it is player 2).

```
public boolean cointoss() { 
  int toss = Random.nextInt(1); // Or is this random causeing it????
  String HorT;
  String callHorT;
  boolean returnMe = true;
  if ( toss == 0) {
    HorT = "Heads";
  } else {
    HorT = "Tails";
  }
  if ( p1Choose == true ) {
    System.out.println( p1Name + " choose Heads or Tails!");
    callHorT = scan.next();
    if( HorT != callHorT) {
      System.out.println("You lose!");
      returnMe = false;
    }
    if( HorT == callHorT) {
      System.out.println("You lose!");
      returnMe = true;
    }
  } else if ( p1Choose ==false ) {
    System.out.println( p2Name + " choose Heads or Tails!");
    callHorT = scan.next();
    if( HorT != callHorT) {
      System.out.println("You lose!");
      returnMe = false;
    }
    if( HorT == callHorT) {
      System.out.println("You lose!");
      returnMe = true;
    }
  }
  if (p1Choose == true ) {
    p1Choose = false;
  }
  if (p1Choose == false) {
    p1Choose = true;
  }
  return returnMe;
}
```

I get this error saying non-static method cannot be refrenced by a static context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're barking up the wrong tree.  The presence or absence of the `static` keyword is the only thing that makes a method static or not.

Comment: So what do I have to do... put static in the method top?

Comment: It's an ill-wind that blows nobody good: your upvote of my answer put my reputation over 10,000 and now I have Moderator privilege.  Years from now, historians will look back and lament, if only he used his privilege for good, instead of for evil...

Comment: @OladamOladam -- yes, in the function declaration: `public static boolean cointoss()`

Comment: Happy "Moderator privilege" acquisition day!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are thinking like that. I don't see anything in your code, that may force you to think like that.
A method can be static if it have a static modifier in its signature. Other then it can't be static. A static or non-static does not depend on the internal structure of the method.
But, there is one thing, you can't use any non-static method or variable from your static method. This part may trouble you to think like that your are now thinking. When you use if-else you may use some non-static variable but when use switch you may does not need to use those.
Request you to check this part.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you're misinterpreting your error...**

> int toss = Random.nextInt(1); // Or is this random causing it????

**`nextInt()` is not a static method on `Random`.  Try this instead:**

```
Random r = new Random();
int toss = r.nextInt(1);
```

Comment: In the top of my class i constructed a Random named "Random". Wouldn't that be the same thing as    Random r = new Random();